# SQL Server 2008 Full Text Search – SLOW

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm using asp.net with SQL Server 2008 SP2

I have one table with Full Text Search Enabled.

My Hardware is: 2GHZ Quad-Core, 4GB RAM, SAS HDD.

The table has around **5 Million records**, and its structure is:

```
Pages table:

ID (INT)
GroupID (INT)
GroupStart (bit)
Col1 varchar(900)
Col2 nvarchar(450)
Col3 nvarchar(450)
Col4 nvarchar(450)
Col5 nvarchar(450)
```

i have a fts index on the primary key ID.

I'm using the following query to search the table:

```
SELECT * FROM (  
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(  ORDER BY  KEY_TBL.Rank DESC  ) AS RowNumber , COUNT(*) OVER() as TotalRows  
FROM Pages p  
INNER JOIN  
CONTAINSTABLE(Pages, *,N' FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, movies)') AS KEY_TBL  
ON p.ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]  
WHERE  (p.GroupID IS NULL OR p.GroupStart = 1) 
) LS  
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 0 AND 10  
ORDER BY RowNumber ASC;
```

The query takes **1s** to complete if total rows is about 500.

and takes **5s** to complete if total rows is about 10,000.

and takes **60s** to complete if total rows is about 100,000.

Any idea why is the query taking so long?

Is there something wrong in my query , sql server or is it a hardware problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan? What is the biggest hit? Other thoughts: what happens if you take away the `COUNT(*) OVER()`; also, how long does just the `CONTAINSTABLE` take (with ROW_NUMBER) - I'm wondering if the join is expensive. Lots of variables - hard to give a complete answer...

Comment: thx for the answer. i just checked exactly that. removing the COUNT(*) OVER() drops the 60s (of 100,000 results) query to 3s!!

Comment: so what would i do next? the count(*) over() takes most of the time , any way to improve that?

Answer (score 1):

Full text search is only useful to search text within varchar or text fields,  it will not speed up queries.   You would need to add more indexes to the table to do that.

In general the query seems overly complicated,  but you haven't explained what the query needs to do.  I think the query needs to be optimized.

Comment: The purpose of the query is to get Paged results from the pages table , based on the matches of the FTS (col1-col5) that have GroupID IS NULL OR GroupStart = 1. What kind of index will help the speed?

Comment: If you remove the count clause how fast does the query execute? ... If so how often is the table updated?   If it isn't updated often consider keeping a record count in a seperate table and update it via a trigger when the table is updated,  or if you have a single update source fire the count in a SP on update.

Comment: its a count of results based on full text query , you cant keep a count for each search query.

Answer (score 1):

Consider restricting number of matches returned by CONTAINSTABLE -> `CONTAINSTABLE(Pages, *,N' FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, movies)', 100 )`

Comment: thanks for the answer , BUT thats not really a solution i need to get all results.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I feared. Truth is, you won't get any reasonable performance from FT queries over 5 millions rows. You need to find a way around. Could you post exactly the requirement for this query? Ie. would it be acceptable to ignore FORMSOF and maybe provide some kind of different search logic?