# SQL Server Full text search slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm have created a catalog for full text searches:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[full_text](
[client_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[file_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[page_number] [int] NULL,
[contents] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_full_text] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

create fulltext catalog dd_full_text;
GO

create fulltext index on full_text(contents)
key index PK_full_text on dd_full_text with change_tracking auto
GO
```

I'm using the same query for testing:

```
SELECT *
FROM full_text
WHERE CONTAINS(contents, '"ban*" AND NOT "sab*"');
GO
```

First queries are fast but after some minutes making the same query it turns more slower. During this test I'm not inserting new rows.

Please see this table:

Response Time ms

1. 2266
2. 3250
3. 3459
4. 11841 (after 10 minutes)
5. 15391

I have investigated other posts like:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093909/sql-server-full-text-search-too-slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548172/sql-server-full-text-search-very-slow)

[SQL Server 2008 Full Text Search – SLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078173/sql-server-2008-full-text-search-slow)

[SQL Server Full Text Search Very Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548172/sql-server-full-text-search-very-slow)

but I can't find a solution.

Comment: How fast is it after you reindex/rebuild? Does the server have plenty of RAM and CPU? Also is it after some time or after a number of usages it starts slowing down?

Comment: If I rebuild the index using this query: alter fulltext catalog dd_full_text rebuild, I get a response in 800 ms. Server has enough RAM and CPU to process this request ;) Ocurrs after some time.

Comment: But does the server see a lot of memory swapping? Could be things are pulled out of memory and stored on slow(er) disks?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I will check it deeply, but I don't think so. Our production servers are allocated in Azure. We never had this kind of problem... In a local server works perfectly.

Comment: Is the table in production, is there data manipulation while you query the table? It could be that your index is being propagated as data is modified, resulting in slowing down your queries. You can try `SET CHANGE_TRACKING MANUAL` and START UPDATE POPULATION when you need it.

Comment: Hi Raul, although the table is on production is not being using, only by me for testing purposes.

Comment: If I set change_tracking Manual I see no changes, still not working :S

Comment: If it works fine locally but not in Azure - I'd try and contact support to see if they have some metrics / insight.